# Invalid IsolationLevel parameter: must be ReadCommitted or Serializable

Tags: c#, oracle

In my .NET 3.5 project, I have created an OracleConnection object called conn.

Then i create a Transaction object as follows :

```
using (OracleTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead))
```

WHen the control goes to the Transaction creation line, it gives an exception as

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled
>   Message="Invalid IsolationLevel
>   parameter: must be ReadCommitted or
>   Serializable."
>   Source="System.Data.OracleClient"

Has anyone faced this problem ? Why can i not set it to RepeatableRead ?

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oracle only supports read commited or serializable isolation levels.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/consist.htm#sthref1972